# Find the Upper bound for f(n) to determine O(g(n))

Tags: algorithm

how do I solve the equation for **n** with the equation as

```
 n^4 + 100n^2 + 50 <=2n^4 .
```

The answer to this equation says this equation is true for all

```
 n >=11.
```

Comment: subtract 2n^4 from both sides and then calculate the roots

Comment: I'm not sure how you are getting 11 exactly. Can you show the process you used to get to that answer? Also, which if `f(n)` and which is `g(n)`?

Comment: This is a question from "Data Structure and Algorithm Made easy in Java".Author has not mentioned the steps for arriving at a solution but the solution has been mentioned that this equation holds true for all n > =11.

Comment: @indra feel free for any queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be very easily solved by basic rearrangement.

```
n^4 + 100n^2 + 50 <= 2n^4

100n^2 + 50 <= n^4

50 <= n^4 - 100n^2

Using a^2 - b^2 = (a + b)(a - b)

50 <= (n^2 - 10n)(n^2 + 10n)

Taking n common

50 <= n^2(n - 10)(n + 10)

50/n^2 <= n^2 - 100
```

**The left side is always positive**, which means the right side must be positive which clearly means that `n>=11, also for n>=11`, the function on the right side will always increase, whereas the function on the left side will always decrease, **hence the solution is all numbers n>=11.**

Comment: Thank you @Dante...You are awesome

Comment: @indra You always try some rearrangement and arrive at a condition for solving such conditions